# python can't find google cloud module

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I spun up a instance on google compute and `google-cloud` came install but when I try and run my python code: `python3 sensorgen.py`, I get this:

```
root@nomad-clients-rp-4bhr:/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages# python3 ~/sensorgen.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/sensorgen.py", line 6, in <module>
    from google.cloud import pubsub_v1
ImportError: No module named 'google'
```

but it is installed....

```
root@nomad-clients-rp-4bhr:/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages# pip3 show google-cloud
---
Metadata-Version: 2.1
Name: google-cloud
Version: 0.34.0
Summary: API Client library for Google Cloud
Home-page: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python
Author: Google Cloud Platform
Author-email: googleapis-publisher@google.com
Installer: pip
License: Apache 2.0
Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages
Requires: 
Classifiers:
  Development Status :: 7 - Inactive
  Intended Audience :: Developers
  License :: OSI Approved :: Apache Software License
  Operating System :: OS Independent
  Programming Language :: Python :: 2
  Programming Language :: Python :: 2.7
  Programming Language :: Python :: 3
  Programming Language :: Python :: 3.4
  Programming Language :: Python :: 3.5
  Programming Language :: Python :: 3.6
  Topic :: Internet
You are using pip version 8.1.1, however version 18.0 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

I've done `pip3 install google-cloud --upgrade`...did and uninstall and reinstall, but still no go....

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you want to use pubsub with python, according the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-usage-python) you should install the module with the following command:

```
pip install --upgrade google-cloud-pubsub
```

If this doesn't work you can update pip and pip3 with apt:

```
sudo apt install python3-pip python-pip
pip install --upgrade google-cloud-pubsub
```

Answer (score 1):

Just try `pip install google` and re-execute the python script
Also do upgrade the pip